# how to strip all characters except for alphanumeric and underscore and dash?

Tags: php, pcre

I'm not an expert with regex:(
I'm trying to to strip all characters from the string except for alpanumeric and underscore and dash.
Is this the correct syntax?:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-]+/i", "", $string);
```

Comment: It would take 2s to test it and know the result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, but it can be optimised slightly:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w-]/', '', $string);
```

`\w` matches alphanumeric characters and underscores.  This has the added advantage of allowing accented characters if your locale allows.

Comment: don't you have to add + after square brackets to specify that pattern inside of square brackets may repeat?

Comment: @Andre Regex patterns in PHP (as opposed to Javascript for example) are automatically global.  This means that every character matched by a regex will be replaced.  So, taking a string `.]`, this regex matches the `.`, replaces it with a blank string, then matches the `]` and does the same.

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks like it will work.  You may want to add spaces since they're not an alphanumeric character:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_-\s]+/i", "", $string);
```

Comment: i modifier is "case insensitive"

Comment: The `/i` means it's already case-insensitive, no need to add capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. :)

http://codepad.org/lkJTRP0P